# Is Levi-Civita tensor strictly covariant, strictly contravariant, or maybe mixed?

Tags: tensors

It is not so clear to me if the [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) tensor is strictly covariant, contravariant, or mixed, i.e., should I write the componants $\epsilon^{ij}$, $\epsilon_{ij}$, or maybe $\epsilon_i^{ \,\,j}$ or $\epsilon_{\text{ } j}^i$ or whatever...

Comment: Generally, subscripts are used with this pseudotensor. However, that is for notation. For use, it can be either covariant or contravariant.

Comment: How can it be either covariant or contravariant? I don't understand